# Joining two dictionaries in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose that I have two distinct dictionaries `Dictionary<string,string> Da` and  `Dictionary<string,int> Db`

Db holds the counts of sub-level items

```
var Db = new Dictionary<string,int?>{{"sub1",10},{"sub2",30},{"sub3",70}...};
```

where Da holds the mapping of sub-level to top level:

```
var Da = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"sub1","top1"},{"sub2","top1"},{"sub3","top2"}};
```

If I want to aggregate the numbers at top level,

```
{{"top1",40},{"top2",70}...}
```

how would I go about it in linq? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  The joining? The re-grouping?

Comment: Note that your initialization for `Da` is invalid because you have two items with the same key.  Maybe you need to reverse your keys and values?

Comment: Is it `Dictionary<string,int?>` or `Dictionary<string,int>`?

Comment: Thank you D Stanley, Your comments helped me realize the flaw of the setup. I am looking for duplicate questions now because I became a join and group by keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var result =
    Da
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).Sum(sub => Db[sub]));
```

Basically, you group `Da` by the value (which is like "top1" and "top2").

Then from such grouping, you create a dictionary. The key for such dictionary items would be the key of the grouping (e.g. "top1").

To calculate the value for each item in the new dictionary, we first select the subs for each group like "sub1" and "sub2" and use the `Db` dictionary to get the counts for each one of them and then calculate the sum.

If the `Db` dictionary is actually `Dictionary<string,int?>`, then you need to handle `null` values by using the `GetValueOrDefault` method like this:

```
var result =
    Da
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).Sum(sub => Db[sub].GetValueOrDefault()));
```